# passing external data from PHP to Typescript / Ecmascript module

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I still can't find best way to pass data my external typescript files.
I convert TS to ES6 modules and this complicate things.
I got following code in my EntityList.ts

```
export class EntityList {

constructor( encryptedInstance: string ) {
    this.encryptedInstanceId = encryptedInstance;
}
```

I use PHP to generate code what create instances of this class. I need to create some fake JS module to do that:

```
    $this->script = new Script();
    $this->script->addCommonImport( 'EntityList', 'EntityList' );
    $this->script->addScript( "new EntityList( '{$list->getEncryptedInstanceId()}' );"
```

which generates some ugly code like this

```
<script type="module">import {EntityList} from "/js/Dho/EntityList";
new EntityList( 'list51' );</script>
```

Is there a better way to pass data to ES6 modules? Thanks

Comment: I don't see what's so ugly about that. Of course you shouldn't create one script per entitylist instance, but one script with all objects that your application needs.

Comment: Make sure to properly string-escape the `$list->getEncryptedInstanceId()` part